# How to read multiple files once using 'fread' in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, fread, data-wrangling

I need some help for reading multiple files (1.snplist,2.snplist, 3.snplist...) at once. Right now, I am using this,

```
library(data.table)
a1 <- fread('1.snplist')
a2 <- fread('2.snplist')
a3 <- fread('3.snplist')
```

How can I read all files in R at once, with different file names, a1,a2,a3...a22.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to list all files that you want to read. Then, you could use a loop to capture the data in a list like so:

```
filelist <- list.files(pattern='.snplist')
datalist <- list()
for(i in seq_along(filelist)) {
  datalist[[i]] <- fread(filelist[i])
}
```

Note we use `seq_along` instead of `1:length(filelist)` to avoid errors in case `filelist` is empty (length 0).